# How to recover Ubuntu installed with Wubi with corrupted GRUB

Tags: windows, grub2, wubi, mbr

I have ubuntu installed inside Windows 7 using Wubi.

Yesterday, I tried installing Ubuntu using GRUB but it seem that GRUB was corrupted. To recover, I fixed the MBR using the Windows 7 CD.

Now Windows 7 is booting from GRUB menu, but when I select Ubuntu the system reboots.

How can I fix the problem of booting into Ubuntu? I can see the Ubuntu installed in the Windows 7?

Comment: If you have found an answer suitable of accepting, please do so immediately.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1), a free tool which is like Grub editor for the Windows Boot Manager.

The steps involved would be :

- Install EasyBCD
- Add an entry for Ubuntu (Wubi) using EasyBCD
- Open a command prompt `Win+R -> cmd` and then type `bcdedit`
- Note the entry (device-id) for Ubuntu that you just made
- Run `bcdedit /set {device_id} partition=X:` (This is if your Ubuntu wubi was installed somewhere other than C:\)
- Run `bcedit /set {device_id} path \your_ubuntu_path\winboot\wubildr.mbr` and substitute the correct path to wubuildr.mbr on your system

Source: [How To Restore the Wubi Ubuntu Bootloader](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20340/how-to-restore-the-wubi-ubuntu-bootloader/) via How To Geek

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use the recover function of Windows to go back in time? If I remember correctly, it's under System Tools.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea - it (hopefully) won't mess with the hard drive's boot sector.