# Installation problem with ubuntu 12.10 in windows 8

Tags: 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover Ubuntu installed with Wubi with corrupted GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49210/how-to-recover-ubuntu-installed-with-wubi-with-corrupted-grub)

I cant see the login page of ubuntu 12.10 installation in my PC, and shows some black screen showing GRUB.
I installed it from wubi.exe.
Specifications of my PC
OS-windows 8 pro 32 bit
RAM-1.5GB DDR2
Processor-AMD athlon 64
GPU-NVIDIA GeForce 6100 nForce 405